# How to make a listbox scroll horizontally

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a listbox that contains a long string.

The beginning is not all that relevant for the user which is why I'd like to make the listbox scroll <s>automatically</s> programatically to the right.

You can scroll to the last item vertically but I've not yet found a way to simulate the user scroll to the right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

```
listbox.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
```

Comment: @Junaith What does that mean? What do you meant by auto?

Comment: What I understood from the question is that if the selected item is not visible completely then the horizontal scroll should move to the end to display the last part.. atleast this is my understanding

Comment: @Junaith This is also similar to `Auto` only. If items is fully visible scrollbar will not be shown, but it will not scroll to end. Doing so will be annoying. When you are scrolling vertically horizontal scrollbar will be moved automatically. No user will like that.

Comment: I completely agree that it would be annoying... but I thought thats what the OP wanted. I might be wrong... only OP can confirm

Comment: Junaith is correct, I want to programatically move the horizontal scrollbar to the right-most position according to what is currently displayed in the list box.

Strike the word automatically because you're right, that would be annoying.

But I'm filling the listbox programatically and then uon display I want it be right-sided when the form is shown.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `listbox.HorizontalScrollbar = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Could [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.horizontalextent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) be what you are looking for?

It uses the HorizontalExtent property.

Answer (score 0):

It's no sense and annoying as told by Sriram Sakthivel but it's not impossible

```
        var point = Font.Size ;
        string Mystr = "Gimme all your lovin', all your hugs and kisses too";
        if (point * Mystr.Length > listBox1.Width)
            listBox1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
        listBox1.Items.Add(Mystr);
```

It will show you automatically end of the string in list box

And connect this method to click property in listbox for getting again in left

```
private void gotoleft(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listbox1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set HorizontalExtent = 0 and set HorizontalScrollbar = true.