# how can you add scrolls to the listbox so that they are not only visible but also active, maybe they are not active due to my mistake

Tags: c#, listbox, scrollbar

this is what filling listbox.item looks like

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("Місце {0} | В роботі з {1} | {2} |({3} хв) | {4}", temp[7].Substring(6, 4), temp[8].Substring(11, 5),temp[2], rezult,rezvalSub));
```

this is what the event handler looks like

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem_1(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((((string)listBox1.Items[e.Index]).Substring(((string)listBox1.Items[e.Index]).Length - 1)).Equals("+"))
            {

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), e.Bounds);

            }
            else if ((((string)listBox1.Items[e.Index]).Substring(((string)listBox1.Items[e.Index]).Length - 1)).Equals("-"))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.Bounds);
            }

            else
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds);
            }

            if (e.Index < 0) return;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, (string)listBox1.Items[e.Index], listBox1.Font, e.Bounds, listBox1.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left) ;
         
        }
`
```

this is what it looks like properties if details are required

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEbBE.png)

all I have achieved is made the scrolls visible, but they are definitely not active horizontally,
the text just goes beyond the box sheet and there is no scroll to drag

Comment: You may need to set `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawVariable` and handle the `MeasureItem` event to set the `ItemWidth`. Notice that, whenever you draw something, you are drawing within `e.Bounds`? You say that the text goes beyond the control but it doesn't. You only draw to the control bounds so there's nothing else to scroll to.

Comment: Ah, I see that you already have set `OwnerDrawVariable`. That's the easy part. Now you have actually specify the width of each item. The problem may be that if you use a different width for each item, your filled rectangles will be different. You probably need to measure each item first, find the width of the widest one, then use that width for all items.

Comment: I'm trying to understand you, but I have no idea where exactly it should be written, I'm a beginner in this matter.
Thank you for helping

Comment: `MeasureItem` is an event, just like `DrawItem`, so you handle the former in the same way you would the latter. To understand how the event works, start by reading [the relevant documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). ALWAYS start by reading the relevant documentation. You can then look for examples online, if required. If you still can't work it out, you'll have something to show us to work from. It's not something I have ever done myself and I'm not in a position to create a working example right now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these are the solutions you are looking for but it is worth giving a look:
[How to make a listbox scroll horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453536/how-to-make-a-listbox-scroll-horizontally)  (credits to Sriram Sakthivel)

From official site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.horizontalscrollbar?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: in event and properties added HorizontalExtent = 0 and set HorizontalScrollbar = true. but nothing has changed either, the text is out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

Here are my events now:

```
 private void listBox1_DrawItem_1(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {

            listBox1.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
            listBox1.HorizontalExtent = 0;
            if ((((string)listBox1.Items[e.Index]).Substring(((string)listBox1.Items[e.Index]).Length - 1)).Equals("+"))
            {

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), e.Bounds);


            }
            else if ((((string)listBox1.Items[e.Index]).Substring(((string)listBox1.Items[e.Index]).Length - 1)).Equals("-"))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), e.Bounds);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), e.Bounds);
            }

            if (e.Index < 0) return;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, (string)listBox1.Items[e.Index], listBox1.Font, e.Bounds, listBox1.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left ) ;
         
        }
        private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
        {


            // Cast the sender object back to ListBox type.
            ListBox theListBox = (ListBox)sender;

            // Get the string contained in each item.
            string itemString = (string)theListBox.Items[e.Index];

            // Split the string at the " | "  character.
            string[] resultStrings = itemString.Split('|');

            // If the string contains more than one period, increase the 
            // height by ten pixels; otherwise, increase the height by 
            // five pixels.
            if (resultStrings.Length > 2)
            {
                e.ItemHeight += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                e.ItemHeight += 5;
            }

        }
        private void InitializeOwnerDrawnListBox()
        {
            this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();

            // Set the location and size.
            listBox1.Location = new Point(20, 20);
            listBox1.Size = new Size(240, 240);

            // Populate the ListBox.ObjectCollection property 
            // with several strings, using the AddRange method.
            this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[]{"System.Windows.Forms",
        "System.Drawing", "System.Xml", "System.Net", "System.Runtime.Remoting",
        "System.Web"});

            // Turn off the scrollbar.
            listBox1.ScrollAlwaysVisible = true;
            listBox1.HorizontalScrollbar = true;

            // Set the border style to a single, flat border.
            listBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            // Set the DrawMode property to the OwnerDrawVariable value. 
            // This means the MeasureItem and DrawItem events must be 
            // handled.
            listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
            listBox1.MeasureItem +=
                new MeasureItemEventHandler(listBox1_MeasureItem);
            listBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_DrawItem_1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
        }
```

And view a listbox :

[image]